# Why Isn't My Textview Setting Text In Widget

Tags: android, loops, widget, textview, handler

I'm a noob to android and i'm trying to loop text in two textviews in a widget with text from an ArrayList.  For some reason, the widget is only showing the first text values from the ArrayList and not looping the subsequent values.  I'm sure my Arraylist has multiple values so that's no the problem.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

My Code;

```
void updateStory() {

    tickerheadline = RssReader.rssheadline.get(storyCounter);
    tickerstory = RssReader.rssstory.get(storyCounter);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.headline, tickerheadline );
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.story, tickerstory );
    if (storyCounter==RssReader.rssheadline.size()-1){
        storyCounter = 0;
    }else{
        storyCounter++;
    }
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(R.layout.widget1, remoteViews);

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 
           updateStory(); 
         } } ,5000);  }

}
```

Comment: there is no error.  The text just isn't resetting inside the widget.

Comment: "I'm sure my Arraylist has multiple values so that's no the problem": Have you logged that? From what I can see, this bit of code is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the widget through the AppWidgetManager after each change.

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
```

Comment: thanks for responding. Please check my Edit, i added your suggestion after to my code but it's still not wrking.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: your parameter for appWidgetId isn't right.  Your using the id of your view but it should be the id the system uses for your appwidget passed to you in your AppWidgetProvider.onUpdate() method.